# Searching for rock-hard integers.

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, decimal-expansion, searching

For integer $k\geq 0$  written $d_jd_{j-1}\dots d_1$, where $d_i$ are single-digit integers, define
$$R(k) := 
\begin{cases} d_j^{d_1}d_{j-1}^{d_2} \dots d_{j/2}^{{d_{j/2 + 1}}}, & j \text{ is even.}\\
d_j^{d_1}d_{j-1}^{d_2} \dots d_{(j+1)/2 -1}^{d_{(j+1)/2+1}} d_{(j+1)/2}, & j \text{ is odd.}
\end{cases}
$$
Which is a bit of an eyesore, though some examples may help: $R(1392) = 1^2 * 3^9$, $R(793) = 7^3*9$, $R(12345678) = 1^8 * 2^7*3^6 * 4^5$.

Now, say an integer $n \geq 0$ is *rock-hard* if $R(n) =n$. $0, 1, 2, 3 \dots 9$ are rock-hard. There are no rock-hard two-digit integers. This can be verified in about five seconds with the question: is there a power of $n$ between $10n$ and $10(n+1)$ for $0 < n < 10$? I do not believe there are any three-digit rock hard integers.

**My question:** is there a more efficient way to search for rock-hard numbers than just checking all numbers? Certainly, we can omit $111$, $121 \dots 191$, $11111,$ $11211,$ etc., but can we further narrow down what numbers we check for rock-hardness?

**Motivation:** John Conway did something similar to this, though I can't remember what he did nor find a reference. I believe N.J.A. Sloane chipped in as well.

**Various comments:** $256$ is almost rock-hard but not quite! $256 = 2^6*4$.

Comment: I would just write a program and search through eight digits, which should run quickly.  I suspect there are very few.  After that there are so many ways to miss I am sure there are no more.  Of course, this is just a hand wave.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do much better than checking all numbers... note that any rock-hard integer is equal to a product of powers of $1,2,\ldots,9$; indeed, all rock-hard integers must be *$7$-smooth*.  There aren't that many $7$-smooth numbers... below $N$, there can't be more than $$(\log_2 N + 1)(\log_3 N + 1)(\log_5 N + 1)(\log_7 N + 1)$$
of them.  A simple script verifies that there are only $2867708$ candidates below $10^{48}$, and checking them all turns up only one rock-hard integer with more than one digit ($117649$).